# how to call specific data in database using code igniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

good evening sensei. im newbie in code igniter framework. i want to ask about how to call specific data with code igniter. my code below intended to call picture's name from my database.

**this my Model**

```
function profile_picture(){     
$username = $this->session->userdata('name');
$this->db->select('pict_name');
$this->db->from('picture');
$this->db->where('username="$username"');
$this->db->limit(1);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query;  
}
```

**this is my controller**

```
public function v_profile(){
    $data['ppicture'] = $this->m_profile->profile_picture()->result();
    $data['profile'] = "profile";
    $this->load->view('header',$data);
    $this->load->view('profile',$data);
    $this->load->view('footer',$data);
}
```

**this is my view**

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url()."assets/img/".$ppicture; ?>" class="img-rounded" >
```

the codes above shows error: array to string conversion. how can i fix it? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing array, `result()` provides array so ,

need to change `result()` to `row()`

```
$data['ppicture'] = $this->m_profile->profile_picture()->row();
```

and `$ppicture;` to `$ppicture->pict_name;`

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url()."assets/img/".$ppicture->pict_name; ?>" class="img-rounded" >
```

You can refer to [documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html) for further information

Comment: What if he has more than one row?

Comment: OP is using `$this->db->limit(1);` , so OP is expecting single row data in return :)

Comment: Didn't noticed that! Good answer!

Comment: its work, thanks sensei, u have a good understanding, noticing thats limit :D @JigarShah

Comment: Glad to help you @emo ,  don't forget to upvote answers if you found useful

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
function profile_picture(){     
$username = $this->session->userdata('name');
$this->db->select('pict_name');
$this->db->from('picture');
$this->db->where('username="$username"');
$this->db->limit(1);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();  
}
```

Befor `$query = $this->db->get();` is returning object so `$data['ppicture']` because an object and after that you assinging `$data['profile']='profile';` so its giving error

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

**Change your Modal to**

```
function profile_picture(){     
$username = $this->session->userdata('name');
$this->db->select('pict_name');
$this->db->from('picture');
$this->db->where('username="$username"');
$this->db->limit(1);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();  
}
```

**In your view page**

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/<?php echo $ppicture[0]['table filed name for image'];?>" class="img-rounded" >
```